# Android + Web WebRTC видео трансляция

Tags: java, android, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте. Решил сделать простенький видео чат, на подобии Skype, только для Android и Web. Много информации перечитал по поводу какую технологию выбрать и решил все сделать при помощи WebRTC. Только не знаю как это сделать. Раньше с такими задачами не сталкивался. Помогите информацией, ссылками, примерами.

Comment: Погуглить вместо вас? https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20webrtc&es_th=1

Comment: @metalurgus Спасибо большое! Очень помог!